# Kubernetes - Unable to Fetch Backend Data in Cluster using Axios in Frontend Application

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, kubernetes, axios

I'm currently facing an issue while developing a web application using a frontend that runs on a browser and a backend hosted in a Kubernetes cluster. My frontend uses Axios to fetch data from the backend service. I'm able to successfully fetch data using curl from within a pod in the Kubernetes cluster, but the Axios call from the frontend fails.

Here's the Axios code in the frontend:

```
const backendUrl = `http://backend:8000/bucket-size/`;
const handleButtonClick = () => {
  setLoading(true);
  axios
    .get(backendUrl)
    .then((response) => {
      const size = response.data.bucketsize;
      const unit = response.data.unit;
      setOutput(size + " " + unit);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    });
};
```

**From within a pod in the cluster, I can successfully curl the backend service:**

```
~ $ curl http://backend:8000/bucket-size/
{"status":"success","bucketsize":"1.47","unit":"GB"}~ $
```

**Im getting this error on Axios**

```
Ei {
    message: 'Network Error', 
    name: 'AxiosError', 
    code: 'ERR_NETWORK', 
    config: {...}, 
    request: XMLHttpRequest {...}
    stack: "AxiosError: Network Error\n at s.onerror (http://<IP_address>/static/js/main.ee7b16be.js:2:582358)"
}
```

**Here's the Kubernetes service configuration:**

[image]

I have updated my CORS Policy as well but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. I havent found any satisfactory answer on SO. Can anyone please help?